# How to enter and Exit out of Vim edit mode when using less?

Tags: linux, readonly

I mostly use less when looking through logs or config files as I expect it to be read-only.

However every once in a while I enter into Vim mode where I can make changes to the file I want to be read only. I don't know how I do it. (possibly right click to paste, but still in less). But most importantly I don't know how to exit this mode without writing changes. The usual :q! does not work nor does the stated :quit.

The message I get if trying to type `:quit`:

```
E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)
```

<kbd>Ctrl C</kbd> says `:quit<Enter>` but does not work:

```
Type  :quit  and press <Enter> to exit Vim
```

These are some of what I see at the console, but I cannot control it. It sometimes goes into INSERT mode where I am modifying the file, and I don't know how to stop it.

Searching gives me instructions for vi, not vi in less and the commands don't work. My only solution so far is to just disconnect and hope nothing gets damaged.

Lastly, is there a way to turn off this functionality in less so it can't happen again?

Update:
I was finally able to get out. I typed in `:q!` like I had before, but at the bottom it said "recording". Also, if I would start typing it would go into INSERT mode. I still don't know how got into it or how I got the recording prompt.

As suggested by roaima I searched in the man pages, I have before. I found `v` goes into edit mode. I not sure how I would press v as ctrl+v does not do it, neither does a right click. Also, with v it flashes for a second and loads at the bottom of the page. I also noticed that I could not type right away and could not exit with `:q!`. I tried Esc, and then Ctrl+C which gave :quit prompt where :q! worked. I feel I am still missing how I have been accidentally entering this mode and how to guarantee a safe exit.
I did find that edit does not work on standard input so `less filename | less` is a workaround to ensure I can't edit accidentally.

Comment: Have you read the reference documentation for `less`? See `man less`

Comment: I have looked through it, but I have not found the Vi/Vim section. Is it possible to search man pages?

Comment: Yes, you can search with `man less | less`. The editor command in just `v`. I wonder if I used ctrl+v to paste not realizing I was in the console, however I still think there have to be other ways to get into it. Still more progress than before. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the documentation for less (`man less`) it's possible to find that the key combination to enter `vi` (or your other preferred editor) is <kbd>v</kbd>:

> **`v`** Invokes  an  editor  to edit the current file being viewed.  The editor is taken from the environment variable `VISUAL` if defined, or `EDITOR` if `VISUAL` is not defined, or defaults to "`vi`" if neither `VISUAL` nor `EDITOR` is defined.  See also the  discussion  of `LESSEDIT` under the section on PROMPTS below.

You can search for text in `less` with `/`, just like you would in `vi`. (`/vi` <kbd>Enter</kbd> will find the next instance of those two letters; use `n` for the next instance.) As always, use <kbd>ZZ</kbd> or <kbd>:q!</kbd> to exit `vi`.

As mentioned in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/750014/how-to-enter-and-exit-out-of-vim-edit-mode-when-using-less?noredirect=1#comment1426872_750014) you can override the default editor setting for `less` by setting the environment variable `LESSEDIT`:

> The default value for `LESSEDIT` is:
>
> ```
> %E ?lm+%lm. %g
> ```
>
> Note that this expands to the editor name, followed by a `+` and the line number, followed  by the shell-escaped file name.

For example, this will set `false` to be the editor, i.e. you won't be able to use <kbd>v</kbd> to edit the file:

```
LESSEDIT=false less /var/log/syslog
```

You can also use `less` on *stdin*, which can't be edited. However, this is far less efficient and could become a memory hog for a large file:

```
less </var/log/syslog
```

You may also want to investigate setting `LESSSECURE=1`.

Comment: Another useful thing to do when finding yourself in an unwanted vi editing session is to press `Esc` twice before `:q!` and `Enter`.  The two presses of `Esc` will ensure the editor is not in Insert mode and will pay attention to `:q!` as a command.